# Is it possible to get to the bus within one hour after landing on Værnes airport (TRD)

Tags: airport-transfer, norway, trd

I'm flying from Germany (DUS) to Trondheim (TRD). My flight will land at 22:40, and the last bus to the city of Trondheim will depart at 23:40. Is one hour enough to walk from the gate, collect luggage and walk to the bus terminal?

I am not familiar with the size / complexity of the Trondheim Værnes airport, hence I'm asking this question.

Comment: I have done this, on a flight from Amsterdam, which arrived Trondheim at 22:50.  TRD is a small airport and there was no difficulty in catching the last bus into the city.  I actually lingered in the duty-free shop for a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TRD is a relatively small airport (as compared to Dusseldorf for example).

In addition to that, your flight is inside the Schengen area, this means that there are no customs/passport checks, no lines to wait in.

Therefore you walk out of the plane, go straight into the baggage claim, get your bag and then walk to the bus stop.

One hour is more than enough, don't worry about it.

Comment: Assuming the flight isn't late that is!

Comment: I should add that the bus stop is just several metres away from the baggage claim area.